# Shopify not calling on my fulfillment /fetch_tracking_numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

I am Developing a new warehouse integration for the company I work for as there was not existing solution.

I have gotten almost every feature to work including

fulfillment request and stock requests and even registered a carrier service for real time shipping rates however for some reason i can not get the 
/fetch_tracking_numbers call to fire from shopify according to the documentation

"Once per hour Shopify will make a request to this endpoint if there are any completed fulfillments awaiting tracking numbers from the remote fulfillment service."

however I have added logs to the call so i can trouble shoot it however it seems that shopify never makes this call to the server.

If I visit the url myself i can fire the code (logs and all) however it doesn't seem like shopify is doing so

In the install I made sure to provide a valid call back url (thats why fetch stock works fine) and set the tracking support field to true but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

One way to be sure would be ensure that a product's variant is set to your custom fulfillment company. Then complete a bogus order for the product. Now fulfill it. Once you have fulfilled it, Shopify will poll your end point for order's and their tracking numbers. It works fine for me... but I am thinking maybe you're waiting for Shopify and nothing is actually fulfilled.

Comment: The product Vairent is set to the custom fullfillment company however I am still not getting any calls to my server from shopify for tracking numbers. I tried both completing the fullfillment and leaving it as pending just to see if I get a call from shopify but I am still not getting anything.

Comment: So, you do a GET on your Fulfillment Services and you see it, and the correct endpoint. OK.. check.. You do a POST to your endpoint to prove it works... all that remains is to ask Shopify to fix the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I am probably too late to answer this but Shopify will make calls to this only if

1) you have "completed" fulfillments

2) tracking number for this completed fulfillments is pending.

You need to mark "complete" a fulfillment after shipping all the order line items